# How can I replace / with . in a file using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to figure out how to replace the '/' in a date (20/01/1990) with '.' (20.01.1990). I do understand to do the whole file is `'s/\//./g'`, but there are urls in the file so it replaces those '/' with '.' which is not what I need. Is there any way to make it apply to only certain columns? I say there is a way with perl but I am working in bash

Answer (score 3):

Just use a different delimiter that's not part of your line.

```
echo 'http://www.google.com  (20/01/1990)' | sed -r 's@([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)@\1.\2.\3@g'
http://www.google.com  (20.01.1990)
```

Comment: When I try and run this on my .sed file I get the error: invalid reference \3 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: @AnythingHelpsHere Check your spelling and typing of the command.

Comment: @AnythingHelpsHere Depending on your version of `sed` (and OS) you  may need `sed -E` instead of `sed -r`.

Answer (score 2):

`bash` is a shell, a command line interpreter. It's role is to run commands. `sed` and `perl` are two commands that `bash` or any other shell can run.

Both happen to be interpreters of some programming language, but that's not relevant here. Both are great at text processing as they have been designed for that. `sed` is a standard command but there are many different implementations which are incompatible if you stray outside of what POSIX specifies, `perl` is not but there is only one implementations (though many different versions with different feature level).

Here, using standard `sed` syntax, you can do:

```
sed 's|\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)/\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)/\([[:digit:]]\{4\}\)|\1.\2.\3|g'
```

Which should work regardless of the `sed` implementation provided it's POSIX compliant within the limits specified by POSIX (in this case, as long as the input is valid text, which in practice excludes very long lines, sequences of bytes not forming  valid characters or non-delimited lines, though some implementations like GNU `sed` may accept those as an extension).

With any version of `perl` and any input, you can also write it:

```
perl -pe 's|(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d{4})|$1.$2.$3|g'
```

Or with recent versions or `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's{\d\d/\d\d/\d{4}}{$&=~y|/|.|r}ge'
```

If you want to avoid replacing `1000/10/99999` with `1000.10.99999`, you can use word boundary operators which are available in `perl`, but not in standard `sed` (though some implementations support `\<`/`\>` or `[[:<:]]`/`[[:>:]]` for that as an extension):

```
perl -pe 's|\b(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d{4})\b|$1.$2.$3|g'
```

Or *look-around* operators (again, a feature of `perl` regexps, but not standard sed regexps).

```
perl -pe 's|(?<!\d)(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d{4})(?!\d)|$1.$2.$3|g'
```

You can do something equivalent with standard `sed` with a bit of *programming* (`sed`'s conditional looping construct):

```
sed -e :1 -e 's|^\(.*[^[:digit:]]\)\{0,1\}\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)/\([[:digit:]]\{2\}\)/\([[:digit:]]\{4\}\)\([^[:digit:]].*\)\{0,1\}$|\1\2.\3.\4\5|g; t1'
```